# how to store these two values(s1&s2) in data store of AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Servlet in my AppEngine Application (I am using Eclipse):

```
 public class ServletCheckServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter pw=resp.getWriter();
        String s1=req.getParameter("username");
        String s2=req.getParameter("password");
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I store these two values(s1&s2) in data store of AppEngine?

Comment: Please make note of the edits that I made to your question, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Entity user = new Entity("User");  // define the entity type
    user.setProperty("username", s1);  // add some properties
    user.setProperty("password", s2);
    DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().put(user); //save it
```

Though i would recommend calling these variables something better than **s1 & s2** And not saving the password as plain text in favor of users logging into user app. Moreover, GAE has nice User Api to play with.